# I am trying to use [react-owl-carousel] getting warning in console but this code is running properly in local but not in server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, owl-carousel

```
/** @format */

import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
const Home = () => {
const options = {autoplay: true,autoplayTimeout: 4000,autoplayHoverPause: true,items: 1,mouseDrag: true,stagePadding: 5,center: true,nav: false,margin: 50,dots: true,loop: true,responsive: {0: { items: 1 },480: { items: 1 },575: { items: 2 },768: { items: 2 },991: { items: 3 },1200: { items: 3 },},};
return (<section>
  <div className='container carousel'>
    <h4 className='text-center m-3 head-title'>Our Completed Projects</h4>
    <OwlCarousel {...options}>
      
    </OwlCarousel>
  </div>
</section>
);};
export default Home;
```

`react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

- Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
- If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

Please update the following components: ReactOwlCarousel
`

Answer (score 0):

This is development error this is seen due to some methods are changed by react community this is not big issue because this is also not visible on deployment time you can code further without any problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).